# Combining objects arrays, then displaying them for relevant people

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have many objects that I want to combine, and then display only the ones which have a matching ID to another object.

So for instance; when a user clicks on John, it would display the fishing trips that john went on (there is are matching IDs in the User Info Object and the Fishing Trip Object).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css" />
    <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="plunker" ng-cloak>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <h1>Select relevant information from a list</h1><br>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>ID</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat = "x in userInfo">
          <td>{{x.name}}</td>
          <td>{{x.ID}}</td>
          <td><button ng-click = "viewMore()">View More</button></td>
        </tr> 
      </table><br><br>
    <div ng-show = "showDiv">
      <table><h3>Selected Information</h3>
        <tr>
          <th>Name (Selection)</th>
          <th>Hobby (Selection)</th>
          <th>ID (Selection)</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat = "x in userInfo">
          <td>{{x.name}}</td>
          <td>{{x.hobby}}</td>
          <td>{{x.ID}}</td>
        </tr> 
      </table><br><br>
      <div>
        <h3>Fishing Trips for selected person:</h3>
        {{fishingTrip1}} {{fishingTrip2}}
      </div>

    </div> 

      
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
import angular from 'angular';

angular.module('plunker', []).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  
$scope.userInfo = [{"name":"John", "hobby":"fishing", "ID":"123"},
                     {"name":"Bob", "hobby":"Golf", "ID":"199"},
                     {"name":"Jerry", "hobby":"Football", "ID":"aAAa"}];


$scope.fishingTrip1 = [{"location":"Alaska", "fisherman":"John", "ID":"123"},
                     {"location":"Alaska", "fisherman":"Bob", "ID":"144"},
                     {"location":"Alaska", "fisherman":"Alex", "ID":"161"}];                   

$scope.fishingTrip2 = [{"location":"Colorado", "fisherman":"Sammy", "ID":"111"},
                     {"location":"Colorado", "fisherman":"John", "ID":"123"},
                     {"location":"Colorado", "fisherman":"Jerry", "ID":"aAAa"}];                   
  


$scope.selectedID = null; 

  $scope.viewMore = function(ID){
    $scope.showDiv = true; 
    $scope.selectedID = ID; 
  }; 

});
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/M8X51cmtMmTNNf2S?open=lib%2Fscript.js&deferRun=1

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css" />
    <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="plunker" ng-cloak>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <h1>Select relevant information from a list</h1><br>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>ID</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat = "x in userInfo">
          <td>{{x.name}}</td>
          <td>{{x.ID}}</td>
          <td><button ng-click = "viewMore(x)">View More</button></td>
        </tr> 
      </table><br><br>
    <div ng-show = "showDiv">
      <table><h3>Selected Information</h3>
        <tr>
          <th>Name (Selection)</th>
          <th>Hobby (Selection)</th>
          <th>ID (Selection)</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat = "x in userInfo">
          <td>{{x.name}}</td>
          <td>{{x.hobby}}</td>
          <td>{{x.ID}}</td>
        </tr> 
      </table><br><br>
      <div>
        <h3>Fishing Trips for selected person:</h3>
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="trip in fishingTripsToShow">{{trip.location}}</li>
      </div>

    </div> 

      
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And in your js file

```
import angular from 'angular';

angular.module('plunker', []).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  
$scope.userInfo = [{"name":"John", "hobby":"fishing", "ID":"123"},
                     {"name":"Bob", "hobby":"Golf", "ID":"199"},
                     {"name":"Jerry", "hobby":"Football", "ID":"aAAa"}];


$scope.fishingTrip1 = [{"location":"Alaska", "fisherman":"John", "ID":"123"},
                     {"location":"Alaska", "fisherman":"Bob", "ID":"144"},
                     {"location":"Alaska", "fisherman":"Alex", "ID":"161"}];                   

$scope.fishingTrip2 = [{"location":"Colorado", "fisherman":"Sammy", "ID":"111"},
                     {"location":"Colorado", "fisherman":"John", "ID":"123"},
                     {"location":"Colorado", "fisherman":"Jerry", "ID":"aAAa"}];                   
$scope.fishingTripsToShow = [];


$scope.selectedFisherman = null; 

$scope.viewMore = function(selectedFisherman){
  $scope.showDiv = true; 
  $scope.selectedFisherman = selectedFisherman;
  $scope.fishingTripsToShow = [];
  $scope.fishingTrip1.forEach(function(f){
    if(f.fisherman == $scope.selectedFisherman.name){
      $scope.fishingTripsToShow.push(f);
    }
  });
  $scope.fishingTrip2.forEach(function(f){
    if(f.fisherman == $scope.selectedFisherman.name){
      $scope.fishingTripsToShow.push(f);
    }
  });
  console.log($scope.fishingTripsToShow);
};

});
```